# python COVID-19 SIRD model ODEs symfit not working

Tags: python, model

I want to fit some real data (of Italy) with SIRD odes using symfit but i cannot understand why my code is not working. I gave as initial value of susceptible a fixed value around 10^4 but when i plot the result they start to zero and go down

here the code:

```
n_susceptible = 4.13 * 10**4


infection_rate, recovery_rate, death_rate= parameters('infection_rate, recovery_rate, death_rate')
S, I, R, De, t= variables('S, I, R, De, t')

model_dict = {
    D(S, t): -infection_rate * I * S ,
    D(I, t): infection_rate* S * I- (recovery_rate + death_rate) * I,
    D(R, t): recovery_rate * I,
    D(De, t): death_rate * I 
}


I0 = I_italy[20]
S0 = n_susceptible - I0
R0 = R_italy[20]
t0 = days[20]
D0 = D_italy[20]
ode_model = ODEModel(model_dict, initial={t : t0, De : D0, I : I0, R : R0 ,S : S0})

fit = Fit(ode_model ,De=D_italy,I=I_italy,  R=R_italy, S=None,t=days)

fit_result = fit.execute()
```

Comment: why do you have a `r` tag on this? defintely you need help with/in python, why include R?

Comment: @Onyambu I have deleted the `r` tag, if the OP wants it back please explain why.